# Every npm command takes forever

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10

I did clean install of node.js & npm on Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134).

Every single npm command I run from windows command line (even npm --version) instantly takes up to ~50% of processor and runs forever (I tried waiting even an hour for nmp --version, but it didn't finish).

I realize lot of similar questions have been asked on SO, but usually people had problem only with install command or the commands took a long time (not forever though), whereas in my case EVERY command takes forever + eats about half a processor. Of course, I tried practically everything that was suggested in those question, but nothing helped.

Comment: Difficult to answer, but if npm fails you, try yarn instead

Comment: @Federkun I was hoping maybe someone has encountered something similar, doesn't hurt to ask here.

Comment: I'm having a big problem with npm as well, every command takes 5 seconds before I see any output.  But it does eventually finish in my case.